# Grating orientation & frequency which induces highest gamma

Tags: perception, vision, theoretical-neuroscience

I am doing some research on perception and gamma activity in V1 area.
To check some of my results I need to find an experimental result, from which I would know which orientations and frequencies of grating are most "popular" in V1. So I need to know two things:

**1: Which orientation(s) induces most gamma?**
The experiment could be something like: take few monkeys/people, show them bunch of gratings with different orientations and record gamma. The orientations which induced highest gamma level is what I want to know.

**2: Which grating frequency induces most gamma?**
The experiment could be something like: take few monkeys/people, show them bunch of gratings of different frequency patterns and record gamma. The frequencies which induced highest gamma level is what I want to know.